# Can't authorize my bot user in discord API with curl

Tags: php, curl, discord

I'm try to send PATCH request with curl to give for user role.

```php
$curl = curl_init("https://discordapp.com/api/v8/guilds/935503210934833192/members/" . $userid);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
$data2 = array(
  "roles" => 935504716505436200,
);
$data2 = json_encode($data2);
$headers2 = ["Authorization: Bot token", "Content-Type: application/json"];
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PATCH");
$role_result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
die(var_dump($role_result));
#header("Location: user.php");
```

But always get this error `string(43) "{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}"`, what i'm can do wrong? I'm sure token is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I can see you are trying to `PATCH` a guild member, but you are not calling the right API URL.

`/guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id}` - as you can see, you need to provide the user's ID you want to `PATCH`.

Comment: So i'm set user id, i'm try this code on reqbin and replaced `"https://discordapp.com/api/v8/guilds/935503210934833192/members/" . $userid` to  `"https://discordapp.com/api/v8/guilds/935503210934833192/members/myidhere"` and have same error. I think problem not in user id, problem in auth headers or something like that.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried modifying the `Content-Type` header from `application/json` to `X-Audit-Log-Reason`? Because the supported endpoint for patching guild's members is `X-Audit-Log-Reason` as I can see.

Comment: Tried now and see same error. I'm py coder and i'm check my code, can't understand why  this working for py and not working for php + curl. Maybe i'm need use some formatter like json_encode for header.
```py
headers2 = {"Authorization": f"Bot {token}", "Content-Type": "application/json"}
url2 = f"https://discord.com/api/v8/guilds/{msg.guild.id}/members/{user.id}"
data2 = {"communication_disabled_until": f"{timeout}"}
data2 = json.dumps(data2)
requests.patch(url=url2, data=data2, headers=headers2)
```

Comment: And why don't you script the bot using Python, if you say that it is working when using Python than using PHP + cURL?

Answer (score 0):

So, as I can see you are trying to PATCH a guild member, but you are not calling the right API URL.

/guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id} - as you can see, you need to provide the user's ID you want to PATCH.